# How can I rerun cables along stairs where a wall is being removed?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, stairs, junction-box

I want to partially take down the wall that currently serves as my staircase handrail.  I will replace that portion of the wall with a cable rail.

[image: Picture taken while the house was under construction. The portion to be removed is outlined in blue.].

The picture above was taken while the house was under construction.  The portion to be removed is outlined in blue.

As you can see, the portion I want to remove has some cables run through it.  What's the best way to deal with them?

I figured I will most likely have to "take in" the extra cable length and connect each side in a cable box using 6-in pigtails.  Would I be able to run the cables diagonally along the lower 2x6?  Are there any requirements I should be aware of (I live in Washington state)?

I only know about cable stapling/clamp distances (< 8 in from a plastic box, < 12 in from a metal box, < 4 ft 6 in along framing), distance to the face of the stud (>= 1 1/4 in without metal plate protection), and the general height of the cable box (12-18 in).

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Big props for taking pre-drywall pictures. I'm no pro, but it looks like you'll have to demo more than just the railing area. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It looks like all of the cables entering/exiting that area also terminate in a box in that area. If so, you simply just need to disconnect them, drill new holes, and re-route the wires. Since they are going to the same spot, the length should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a box to extend the cables it will need to remain accessible. I would pull back to before the triple and drill down , it looks like there might be a level below (I think I see studs below And fire block foam where they go down?) After dropping down, route the cables back to their original termination. 
Without knowing more about the structure, that would be the best advice I could give but it may not be easy as I can’t tell the direction of the floor joists. I prefer punching through TJI’s over 2x’s when roping a house.

Comment: "PUNCHING AND ROPING????  WERE YOU A COWBOY IN A PREVIOUS LIFE??

Comment: I have 6 horses in the barn out back so I guess I am. Maybe we call rough wiring a house roping because we are in the west. LOL.+